# How to toggle popup in react-leaflet on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

I tried everything I found on google and I can't figure out how to trigger the popup.

```
<Marker
  position={this.props.position}
  onMouseOver={() => { openPopup() }}
  onMouseOut={() => { closePopup() }}
>
  <Popup>
     "HI"
  </Popup>
</Marker>
```

Note: I know I can't trigger the function openPopup there its just to show where I want to implement the trigger function to toggle the popup on mouse hover.

Can someone please help, Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Leaflet Marker object](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#marker) is accessible via `event.target` property of `mouseover` and `mouseout` events, so popup could be opened/closed like this:

```
<Marker
    position={position}
    onMouseOver={(e) => {
      e.target.openPopup();
    }}
    onMouseOut={(e) => {
      e.target.closePopup();
    }}
  >
    <Popup>Sydney</Popup>
  </Marker>
```

[**Demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/zljy3845r3)

Answer (score 2):

Using React Leaflet v3, the solution is easier and cleaner, use `Tooltip` instead of `Popup`, e.g.:

```
<Marker position={this.props.position}>
  <Tooltip>I appear on mouse over</Tooltip>
</Marker>
```

In particular, I have found useful to also add `sticky` property for `Tooltip`. There are more examples for tooltips in the [documentation](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-tooltips), which covers basic tooltips, sticky tooltips or permanent tooltips, with offsets and many more.

Comment: unfortunately there is no autoPan option for the Tooltip

Comment: @deathfry you can always open a PR, react-leaflet is an active project :)